# display src of html5 audio file

Tags: html, audio, tinymce, html5-audio, src

I have an app that uses tiny mce to embed audio files using html5 so it ends up embedding like this;

```
<audio width="300" height="32" preload="none" controls="controls" src="../upload/blah .MP3"></audio>
```

I would like to however show the name of the file under the player i.e. the src, any ideas of how it can be done?

Comment: javascript? get the src attribute, stuff its contents into a div/span under the player.

Comment: on my knees begging for some sample code!

Comment: with jquery, roughly: `$('#where_you_want_the_src_to_go').html($('audio').attr('src'))`

Comment: tried it out still doesnt work. If i try to alert($('audio').attr('src')); it alerts undefined...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your audio file is embeded inside the tinymce content.
In this case the following should work

```
$('#target_id').html($(ed.getBody()).find('audio:first').attr('src'));
```

Comment: I tried to put the code on the same page that has my tinymce editted as follows $('audio').html($(ed.getBody()).find('audio:first').attr('src')); but it still is not working any ideas why?

Comment: I also tried $("audio").after("<div>"+$('audio').attr('src')+"</div>"); on jsfiddle and it works but on the tinymce text window it does not show. ODD!

Comment: do you have a live example so that i could have a look?

Comment: difficult to tell without the chance to look at it. But there should be a way. Couldn't you create a tinymce fiddle or js fiddle  for this?

Comment: this works extremely well on jsfiddle but could it be that its refusing to work because im using a testarea?   $("audio").each(function(index, value) { 
    $("audio").eq(index).after("<div>"+$(this).attr('src')+"</div>");
   
});

Comment: what do you mean by "testarea"?

Comment: appologies i mean <textarea>

Comment: shouldn't matter - because tinymce uses its own iframe to edit the content

Comment: I have tried to call the script on a page with tinymce but it still isnt working. I even tried to change the <textarea> to a div it shows the src of the embed when i show source but its not appearing next to the audio.